# Can't append a div I created with threejs

Tags: javascript

So I made a function that makes a div in a certain location. Then I load threejs. It's a webgl engine that should run a rotating cube. Now, i want threejs to run inside the div I created. But When I check "container" it outputs null. It's like it doesn't recognise the div is there. What am I doing wrong??

```
//Make div for canvas
function AdDiv(divname)
{
    //make a div that will be used for the canvas
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'placedCanvas';
    iDiv.className = 'placedCanvas';
    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(iDiv);
    console.log("canvas created");
}


function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;
    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}

var myPrettyCode = function()
{
    var scene, camera, renderer, container;
    var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
    var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var SPEED = 0.01;

    function init() 
    {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        initCube();
        initCamera();
        initRenderer();

        //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var container = document.getElementById('placedCanvas');
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement); //This doesn't work??
        console.log(container); //Container seems to output null
    }

    function initCamera() 
    {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 10);
        camera.position.set(0, 3.5, 5);
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    }

    function initRenderer() 
    {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setSize(200, 200);
    }

    function initCube() 
    {
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
        scene.add(cube);
    }

    function rotateCube() 
    {
        cube.rotation.x -= SPEED * 2;
        cube.rotation.y -= SPEED;
        cube.rotation.z -= SPEED * 3;
    }

    function render() 
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        rotateCube();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    init();
    render();
};

loadScript("https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/three.js",myPrettyCode);
```

This is the html page where I do the function

```
<div id="canvasdiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/modelscript.js" async></script>
        <script>
            function codeAddress()
            {
                AdDiv("canvasdiv");
            }
            window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>
```

Comment: where do you call `AdDiv()` ? If you don''t call it then the container div with id `placedCanvas` is never created.

Comment: I load it on a different html page. The div is created and i can see it in the hierarchy. i added it in the first post.

Comment: Maybe check that `AdDiv` is in fact running before you try to find your `placedCanvas`? Throw in some `console.log`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was loading the javascript async. I removed this and the code worked!